# Generate all possible combinations of strings including repeats for given length?

Tags: ruby, string, combinations

I need to generate every possible combination of letters `a` to `z` based on a length.  I know I can do this:

```
('a'..'z').to_a.repeated_combination(2).map(&:join)
```

But the problem is that duplicates are removed.  If the length is 2, I need everything between `aa` to `zz`, including `ab` and `ba`, etc.  I know this is a simple procedure, but I can't get it and my Google fu is off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case you need to use `repeated_permutation` instead. [Array Permutation](http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_125/Array/repeated_permutation)

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
('aa'..'zz').to_a
```

A shortened version looks like:

```
'aa'..'bb').to_a
[
    [ 0] "aa",
    [ 1] "ab",
    [ 2] "ac",
    [ 3] "ad",
    [ 4] "ae",
    [ 5] "af",
    [ 6] "ag",
    [ 7] "ah",
    [ 8] "ai",
    [ 9] "aj",
    [10] "ak",
    [11] "al",
    [12] "am",
    [13] "an",
    [14] "ao",
    [15] "ap",
    [16] "aq",
    [17] "ar",
    [18] "as",
    [19] "at",
    [20] "au",
    [21] "av",
    [22] "aw",
    [23] "ax",
    [24] "ay",
    [25] "az",
    [26] "ba",
    [27] "bb"
]
```

---

EDIT:

> ...I have generate based on a length.

Then use a length.

```
length = 2
(('a' * length) .. ('z' * length)).to_a
```

This is a very fast way of generating the combinations:

```
require 'benchmark'

N = 1_000

1.upto(3) do |length|
  puts %Q[Length: #{ length }, generating "#{ 'a' * length }" to "#{ 'z' * length }"]
  Benchmark.bm(11) do |b|
    b.report('permutation') { N.times { ('a'..'z').to_a.repeated_permutation(length).map(&:join) }}
    b.report('range') { N.times { (('a' * length) .. ('z' * length)).to_a }}
  end
end
```

Which outputs:

```
Length: 1, generating "a" to "z"
                  user     system      total        real
permutation   0.030000   0.000000   0.030000 (  0.028286)
range         0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.009942)
Length: 2, generating "aa" to "zz"
                  user     system      total        real
permutation   0.500000   0.010000   0.510000 (  0.504663)
range         0.240000   0.000000   0.240000 (  0.240362)
Length: 3, generating "aaa" to "zzz"
                  user     system      total        real
permutation  15.350000   0.140000  15.490000 ( 15.535756)
range         6.200000   0.000000   6.200000 (  6.221575)
```

The times for "permutation" got longer than I was willing to wait for a length of `4`. Feel free to run the benchmark on your own machine to test.

Comment: Close, but I have generate based on a length.